# Why is TeamCity having issues with building Microsoft.Estensions.Hosting.WindowsServices?

Tags: .net, nuget, teamcity

I'm trying to run a build on TeamCity where I've increased the version of the package Microsoft.Estensions.Hosting.WindowsServices from 6.0.1 to 7.0.1. Nuget says that this is compatible with .NET 6, which is what my app is using. However, when I run the build I get the following error:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.404\NuGet.targets(132,5): error :
> Found invalid data while decoding.

However, If I put the package back to 6.0.1 TeamCity builds fine.

Is this an issue with the dependencies Microsoft.Estensions.Hosting.WindowsServices has? If it's compatible with .NET 6 I thought this would work out of the box, but doesn't appear to be so.